# Spring JMS defining multiple destinations

Tags: java, spring, jms, jndi, spring-jms

The [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms-destinations) says:

> Destinations, as ConnectionFactory instances, are JMS administered
>   objects that you can store and retrieved in JNDI. When configuring a
>   Spring application context, you can use the JNDI JndiObjectFactoryBean
>   factory class or  to perform dependency injection on
>   your object’s references to JMS destinations.
>
> **However, this strategy
>   is often cumbersome if there are a large number of destinations in the
>   application or if there are advanced destination management features
>   unique to the JMS provider.**

The question is:

How to proceed when I have a large number of destinations in my application?

Using the strategy mentioned above I have to define:

- JndiTemplate
- JndiDestinationResolver
- JndiObjectFactoryBean
- CachingConnectionFactory
- JmsTemplate

For **EACH** destination.

So If I have 20 queues, I'll have to define 100 such beans...

Comment: You can lazily resolve the destinations, you only need a single `JmsTemplate` and `ConnectionFactory` (assuming they all are using the same JMS provider/instance). Everything else can be lazily looked up using the `send(destination, message)` methods on the `JmsTemplate`.

Answer (score 2):

The comment in the Spring documentation makes a note on 'using JNDI for destination endpoints' versus 'not using JNDI for destination endpoints'. So in your case - are your destinations stored in JNDI ? If you don't have to use that, forget about it. Only load your ConnectionFactory (one object) from JNDI or simply create it from scratch.

And then you don't have to assign one Spring bean to each destination. You could have just one Java 'consumer bean' which then uses JmsTemplate. I guess your connection factory is the same, so that's only one `new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory)`. Then do createSession/createConsumer, etc. as needed.

Comment: The problem is that my queues are defined in JNDI files and they are quite large. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a single [`JmsTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html), [`CachingConnectionFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html) and [`JndiDestinationResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/destination/JndiDestinationResolver.html)...

The whole point of using a `DestinationResolver` is to lazily resolve the destinations for you. Use the specific [`send`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#send-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator-) or [`convertAndSend][5]. The`destininationName`will be passed on to the`DestinationResolver` to get the destination.

The only drawback is that you need to use the jndi-name as the destinationName.

```
@Bean
public JndiDestinationResolver jndiDestinationResolver() {
  return new JndiDestinationResolver();
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
  JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
  jmsTemplate.setDestinationResolver(jndiDestinationResolver());
  jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
  return jmsTemplate;
}
```

With this you can use the following to dynamically resolve the destination from JNDI.

```
jmsTemplate.send("jms/queue1", "This is a message");
jmsTemplate.send("jms/queue3", "This is another message");
```